# How to send push notifications to a specific device through fcm without authorization or google account?

Tags: push

I want to have my application receive notifications without forcing the user to be logged in or authenticated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you explain what does authorisation means here?

Comment: @Husyn by authorization, I mean send notifications anonymously from one device to another

Comment: Push Notifications (from FCM or GCM) isn't supported from device to device. You need a backend or Firebase console to send push notifications. Furthermore user is not required to login/authorise in the app to receive Push Notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use Socket IO for your case to send messages from one device to another.

There are many good to have Socket IO frameworks which can consider for your requirement

1. [Signal R in Android](http://www.sathyabaman.com/2016/11/16/signal-r-in-android/)

> SignalR is a new library used to add real-time web functionality to your applications. Signal R uses technology such as
>
> - web sockets
> - Event Source,
> - forever frame
> - long polling
>
> Signal R is capable of selecting the best from those four technology depending on your internet connection and your application stability.
>
> Signal R is used in application such as
>
> - Chatting application
> - Stock market application
> - Real-time gaming

2. [Native Socket.IO](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

> Socket.IO provides an event-oriented API that works across all networks, devices and browsers. Its incredibly robust (works even behind corporate proxies!) and highly performant, which is very suitable for multiplayer games or realtime communication.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm using OneSignal to send notificaitions to the users of my Android app and it's working fine. Moreover, it uses FCM as its base. So, that shouldn't be a problem too. You can segment users thet way you want and send notifications to one or many - upto you. It's all for free and very easy to set up the basics of it. It's here: [OneSignal](https://www.onesignal.com/)